# App rejected for PLA 3.3.1, keeping device awake

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, uiapplication

I haven't been doing this long, but this is the first time that I've had an app rejected.  This is what was in my rejection.

PLA 3.3.1

Your app uses public APIs in an unapproved manner, which does not comply with section 3.3.1 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Specifically, your app contains a mechanism to keep a device awake. Please see attached screenshot(s) for reference.

Since there is no accurate way of predicting how an API may be modified and what effects those modifications may have, Apple does not permit unapproved uses of public APIs in App Store apps.

The screenshot that they included showed my setup screen where I give users the option to have the application keep the device awake.  I tested it, and it only keeps the device awake when in the application.  I did not come up with this idea all by myself.  I've seen it as an option in other apps.

I am not using anything non-apple to do this.  This is my code for keeping the device awake.

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = keepDeviceAwake
```

where keepDeviceAwake is a `Bool` that is turned on or off by a user setting.

Is there something wrong with the way that I'm using this or what I'm doing with it?

To give more of an idea, this app is a counter app.  I was thinking that it would be really annoying to have to keep turning on the iDevice when counting things, so I give the option to keep the device on while in the app.

Comment: You should appeal the decision. Make sure you explain how the app's intended use case justifies leaving the screen on.

Comment: It would be interesting if you could tell us for what functionality does your app need to disable the idle timer.

Comment: Sure.  It's a counter app.  Like the kind that they use in bars to count patrons.  It can be used to count anything, really.  I wrote it so that I could keep track of rubik's cube solves.  Patron counting is  just one possibility and one possibility that proves the usefulness of having it disable the idle timer.  Say you have your iPhone set to shut off after one minute, but your customers come in every couple of minutes.  You'll have to turn the phone on and potentially unlock it every time.  Annoying.  If the idle timer is shut off, then you don't have to do that.

Comment: Check out the app SnoreLab. They keep the phone open with app running to record sounds all night. The screen says "plug in if possible." You may be able to make a similar recommendation in your view and use them as part of your appeal.

Comment: I appealed and it made no difference in the end.  They said that it is against their rules and that any apps that have it in there are violating the rules and will be caught and forced to make changes at some point in the future.  Basically they said, just because you've seen this in other apps, doesn't mean that it's ok and that you should use it.  I removed it and resubmitted the apps this evening.  I also removed it from the pay version.  I'd hate to introduce something that has to be removed later.  We'll see how it goes in a week or so, when they get back to it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation note on `idleTimerDisabled` says:

> You should set this property only if necessary and should be sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists. Most apps should let the system turn off the screen when the idle timer elapses. This includes audio apps. With appropriate use of Audio Session Services, playback and recording proceed uninterrupted when the screen turns off. The only apps that should disable the idle timer are mapping apps, games, or programs where the app needs to continue displaying content when user interaction is minimal

Apple probably feels that your app doesn't fall within the guidelines.

Comment: And I would agree. Giving the user the arbitrary power to keep the device awake is clearly outside the intention here.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't invent the idea.  I've seen it done in apps before.
Even more strange.  I have a lite version of the app and a pay version.  The lite version was rejected.  The pay version was just approved.  Same exact functionality.  Furthermore, my app does meet this criteria - "where the app needs to continue displaying content when user interaction is minimal".

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't arbitrary and capricious. This is Apple. Even they don't know what they'll do next. But it's their football, so what can you do?

Comment: Most likely your paid and lite versions were reviewed by different people/teams at Apple. Same applies to why other apps doing the same get approved. It's not fair, because humans do it and interpretations vary. There is a luck component (i.e., which reviewer you get to review your app).

Comment: Actually, there might be another reason.  The lite version is ad supported.  Perhaps Apple sees keeping the device awake as a grab at more ad revenue.  Though that was definitely not my intention at all, I can see them perhaps having a problem with it for that reason.  That would explain why they rejected this version, but not the pay version.
If that's the reason, then they could have clearly stated it in their rejection.  I'm going to appeal the decision and see if I can get more information out of them.